# Excel If or Vlookup to see if value is equal to either a 2 or 3

Tags: excel

I was creating a simple markup tool to help me find which values was scored a 2 or 3.

IF any of these entries: (H2,J2,N2,P2). #these values are derived from another excel sheet)

has a score of either 2 or 3,

Then True statement = 1 and False Statement = 0

I couldn't figure out how to get this to work:

`=IF((H2,J2,N2,P2)),(2,3),1,0) ???`

`=IF((H2,J2,N2,P2)),2,1,0),IF(AND((H2,J2,N2,P2)),3,1,0)`

or would you use

`=VLOOKUP (value, table, col_index, [range_lookup])`

`=VLOOKUP((2,3),(H2,J2,N2,P2),????, True)?`

Answer (score 0):

Use  OR:

```
=--OR(OR(H2={2,3}),OR(J2={2,3}),OR(N2={2,3}),OR(P2={2,3}))
```

[image]

And, yes it can be done with VLOOKUP:

```
=--OR(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},H2,J2,N2,P2),{2;3},1,FALSE)))
```

Depending on one's version, these formula may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: For some reason, the output conditions is not going according to plan. For example, some values (just random values and not exact) H4 was a 3 but J4 was a 0, N4 was a 2 yet excel was deeming it as a 0

Comment: Change the `AND` to `OR` then.  I misread I thought you want them all to either be 2 or 3 not any.

Comment: @MountMontero if this worked for you please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.